# Reopen queue not working

Tags: bug, status-completed, reviewing, reopen

The reopen queue (for me at least). It's showing an error message "An error occurred when loading the review item. Please try again."

[image: Reopen queue]

I don't have idea if this is occurring with someone else or I'm the chosen one xD

Comment: down for me as well.

Comment: Are you still experiencing this?  We had some database issues around this time (and /review is a heavy hitter)...

Comment: Not at the moment @JarrodDixon Thanks =)